# Updating field only if certain value is found in other table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am stuck on the following issue:
I have two tables in my database. One holds parent elements and one holds child elements. This structure is given and must not be changed.
I now have to update a field for each child. The field may contain 0 or 1 but must not be NULL.
The default value is 0. If the parent holds a certain status, i want to update the field in the child category to 1.
I have tried this so far:

```
UPDATE  'children' AS 'child'
    SET  'foo' = (
        SELECT 1
        FROM 'parents' AS 'parent'
        WHERE 'parent'.'type' = "bar" AND 'parent'.'id' = 'child'.'fk_parents_id'
    );
```

This doesn't seem to work for me as I get an error message stating `foo` must not be null.
I am fairly new to SQL, so I am quite stuck here. Can someone help me out?

Comment: something like `foo = (SELECT CASE WHEN 'parent'.'type' = "bar" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM ...)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if foo can't be NULL. so you have to test if it gets an result and set another value

```
UPDATE  `children` AS `child`
    SET  `foo` = IF(
        EXISTS(SELECT 1
        FROM `parents` AS `parent`
        WHERE `parent`.`type` = "bar" AND `parent`.`id` = `child`.`fk_parents_id`) 
    ,0, 1);
```

Also **never** never use single qutotes for table or coumn names that gives only errors see [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming here that the field `children.foo` is supposed to get the value `0` if the subquery returns `NULL` as no parent with the right conditions was found. In that case the original query fails because for rows with no matching parent the `SET = (...)` part tries to assign `NULL` to a field that is  not nullable.

If the two values directly match to the existence of a matching parent, the query can then be changed to:

```sql
UPDATE  'children' AS 'child'
    SET  'foo' = IFNULL((
        SELECT 1
        FROM 'parents' AS 'parent'
        WHERE 'parent'.'type' = "bar" AND 'parent'.'id' = 'child'.'fk_parents_id'
    ), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     UPDATE  'children' AS 'child'
     SET  'foo' = (
        SELECT 1
        FROM 'parents' AS 'parent'
        WHERE 'parent'.'type' = "bar" AND 'parent'.'id' = 
        'child'.'fk_parents_id'
     ) 
     Where foo >= 0
```